# Android test doesn't start with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I made some test classes to test android application.

```
public class ATest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FooActivity> {
    ......
}

public class BTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FooActivity> {
    ......
}
```

In this case, test methods in BTest don't start.
I guess it is because both of ATest and BTest `extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FooActivity>`.

When I wrote BTest as it `extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BarActivity>`, the test started.

1. How can I start ATest and BTest which extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FooActivity>`?
2. If I can't, why BTest can't start?

I have struggled with these two problem for 6 hours.

Please give your help. Thank you.

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: I made test project with Eclipse as https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Espresso_Setup_Instructions instructs.

Comment: Right click on your project, go to Run As -> Run Configurations. Is "Run a single Test" selected instead of "Run all tests"?

Comment: I solved by myself. I was using GLSurfaceView in FooActivity. The test didn't start because of the GLSurfaceView.